# Not using www in front of my url is slower

Tags: asp.net, domain-name-system

My site resolves and loads much faster when I type www.mydomain.com in my browser compared to when I just type mydomain.com. To be clear, the site loads without typing the www prefix, it is just several seconds longer before the page begins to load when I do that.

What might cause this slowness resolving the url without a www prefix?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check your .htaccess file. There may be a rule that could be the culprit. Would you mind listing it here?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen.

1. Are you sure it is slower?
2. Have you logged non-cached times in Firebug?
3. Are you using any rewriting rules?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a difference in my DNS internal versus external network config. I realized this when I saw that outside name resolution for the missing www was much faster than internal.

Thanks all!